# Bolding a number inside a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, environments

I am using

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circledd[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,color=white,fill=red,draw,inner sep=3.0pt] (char) {#1};}}
```

to draw a circle (in a text) that includes a number.
How can I bold the number inside the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\textbf`

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circledd[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,color=white,fill=red,draw,inner sep=3.0pt] (char) {\textbf{#1}};}}
```

You can also use the `font` key

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circledd[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,color=white, font=\bfseries,fill=red,draw,inner sep=3.0pt] (char) {#1};}}
```